# initializing google map while invisible = bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am getting this bug when initializing a google map - while the canvas is hidden on a (not active) tab. -> It's scrollable and zoomable, but does not extend on the whole canvas, the rest of the canvas remains in grey.

[image]

I am using the jQuery Map Extension (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) to load a gmap on my page. Also there are two tab-views, where on one tab there is no map, and on the other tab there is the gmap.

I have two scenarios (init the map on pageload):
1. page is loaded to show TAB1 (with map)
2. page is loaded to show TAB2 (without map)

in scenario 1 everything is fine, map is displayed and shown, acts normally.
in scenario 2 the map looks like the image above

i tried to initialize the map again, when switching the tabs. but this seems to have no effect whatsoever.

- is there an option to properly re-initialize a gmap element?
- a way to re-inflate the gmap element?
- have you had similar bugs and know a solution for me?

Thanks!
Patric

Comment: problem is when elements are not displayed, they can not calculate widths correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to re-inflate the gmap element - yes google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in earlier answers, the Google Map, when initialized, only renders a map of the size of its container. When the containing element is invisible, the map renders of size 0x0.

You'll want to notify the map that its contain has changed size, by triggering the `resize` event on the map itself.

```
// Assuming "map" is the map object returned by "google.maps.Map"
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Comment: And when do you trigger this? And if the map is already rendered, you would not need to trigger this again.

Comment: @Sparky672 You trigger it every time to container changes. If you are working with a responsive design, you trigger this every single time the window resizes.

Comment: Yes, of course, but that may or may not even be relevant to the OP.   My point is that you do not need to trigger it every single time you visit the tab _after_ you've rendered it the first time.  In other words, you need to test whether the map has already been rendered or you're re-rendering it multiple times for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue/working as intended. You'll have to add a handler to your tabs to initialize the map in the tab after the tab is clicked. Rather, don't initialize your maps until the tab is active.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, this is a known issue.  The solution is to load the map dynamically when you reveal the tab.  I can't see your code, so here is a generic solution that is very straightforward.  Modify whatever function you use for revealing your tab content as follows.  When you load the specific tab, check for map's existence and load if needed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function my_tab_reveal() {  // or whatever function you use for showing your tabs content
        // whatever your code for revealing tab content is here

        if (!loaded) {  // this checks to see if the map is not already loaded
            load(); // this loads the map
        }
    }

    var loaded = false;
    load = function() {
        // your google maps JavaScript code goes here

        // checks tiles to see if map has loaded
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "tilesloaded", function() {
            loaded = true;
        });
    }

});
```